# Get cookie value from an iframe url

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, iframe

I want to get cookie value from an iframe. Iframe have third party url and I have displayed it in my site in a popup as an iframe. So iframe have login and logout functionality. 
I want when user successfully login in, third party site (means in popup iframe url) that time we want to get cookie value from iframe.

Actually i want when user successfully login form my third party url (means iframe in popup) that time we get some value and that value stores in session and close popup.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access cookies from a third-party iframe. It'd be a huge security hole that would let you embed, for example, someone's banking website in a 1x1 iframe and use it to break into their accounts.

Comment: Yes, you told right. But no one solution for getting cookie value.

Comment: @kruti Sure, find a zero-day exploit in all the browsers' security. Good luck.